# bash: [: missing `]' when the test stored in variable

Tags: bash, variable, test

Why this works:

```
[ -r /tmp ] && echo "tt" >/tmp/taa
cat taa
tt
```

But the following doesn't and how to fix that, preserving variable for reusability?

```
COMD='[ -r /tmp ] && echo "tt"'
$COMD >/tmp/taa
bash: [: missing `]
```

Thanks

Edit: `eval` indeed works. However, I don't get why, and in [the question, that mine was marked as a duplicate of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766), there is no explanation either.
Moreover, if the part starting with `&&` is removed it works and even actually returns right results without `eval`:

```
COMD='[ -r /tmp ]'
$COMD
echo $?
0

COMD='[ -r /tmpdddd ]'
$COMD
echo $?
1
```

Comment: `$COMD` is a variable you need either define it as an _alias_ or _function_ or `eval $COMD` it

Comment: If you have not tampered with `/tmp`, everybody (owner, group, others) have read,write,execute permissions, so you need not check for that.

Comment: @sudodus, This is just an example. Moreover, in the real script, the directory in question comes as an input from a user and should be validated either at local or remote (via SSH) machine

Comment: Storing code in a variable is a really bad idea. If you want reusability use a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't expect:

```
var='echo test && reboot'
echo $var
```

To output `test` and then reboot, would you?

Instead, it outputs `echo test && reboot`

That's the same for

```
var='echo test && reboot'
$var
```

Now, where it becomes confusing is that in most Bourne-like shells, it doesn't fail with an error that says that the `echo test && reboot` command is not found. Instead, and unless you have modified `$IFS`, it outputs `test && reboot`.

That's because, in those shells, leaving a variable unquoted applies some sort of split+glob operator.

Because `$var` is not quoted, it is split into words (according to the `$IFS` special parameter): `echo`, `test`, `&&`, `reboot`, and the command to run is derived from the first one (`echo`) and all the words passed as arguments to that command. `&&` is an argument to `echo` there. Only a literal unquoted `&&` would be understood as the `&&` operator of the `sh` language. Like in C, `var="foo, bar"; printf(var)` doesn't mean two arguments are passed to `printf` just because `var` happens to contain `,` which is an operator in the syntax of the C language.

Actually, if we go back in history to the very first versions of Unix in the early 70s, their `sh` (nowadays referred to as the *Thompson shell*) would have run `reboot` there. Well, `sh` back then didn't support variables, but it did have positional parameters.

Here using Unix V1 on a PDP11 emulator:

```
$ cat myscript
echo $1
$ sh myscript 'echo test; reboot'
echo test
No command
$ ls -l /bin/sh
total   12
 88 lxrwr-  1 sys    5312 Jan  1 00:00:00 sh
```

(thankfully, there was no `reboot` command back then, hence the `No command` error).

That may sound crazy by today's standard, but remember Unix V1 ran on machines with a few hundred kilobytes of memory and megabytes of storage, so things had to be kept simple back then. See how that `sh` is significantly smaller than `/bin/true` (the command that does nothing) on a modern system (27KB on my system (not counting the dynamic linker or the dynamic libraries it's linked to) against 5KB for that sh).

Unix V7 in the late 70s came with the Bourne shell, the new `sh` then. A lot more advanced, but still didn't break completely compatibility with its predecessor. Same for csh that came at about the same time on BSD. It's probably the main reason for that awkward behaviour of the Bourne shell: parameter expansion still undergoes some forms of expansion, like that splitting into words and also globbing (but not as far as full sh language re-interpretation as in the early Unix shells as that would be crazy), for backward compatibility with the Thomson shells.

Some shells like `rc`, `fish` or `zsh` (that one a Bourne-like shell) have eventually fixed that later on, but many including `bash` have kept backward compatibility with the Bourne shell.

Now, if you want to interpret a string as shell code, that's what the `eval` command is for:

```
eval "$var"
```

(note the quotes to prevent the split+globbing in Bourne-like shells).

But if you want to store code in a variable, it would make much more sense to use a function like in other languages:

```
f() { echo test && reboot; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the `&&` operator is not recognized after variable expansion. Neither are the quotes: if that worked, it would print `"tt"`. (Try: `cmd='echo "tt"'; $cmd`)

Make it a function instead:

```
checktmp() {
    [ -r /tmp ] && echo "tt"
}
checktmp
```

Functions are for code, variables for data.

Comment: [This is as close as it gets to describe WHY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). However, I'm marking this as solved, as I may use function via SSH also